# Importing descriptor with included import

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Im trying load descriptors from external source. 
When using generated files without imports it works without problem but when proto have imports then while building FileDescriptor I gets DescriptorValidationException:

> Failed to parse descriptor ./descriptors/test.dsc
>   com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$DescriptorValidationException: AccessRequest.date_from: ".google.protobuf.Timestamp" is not defined.

Proto file which i use to get *.dsc file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
message AccessRequest {
    int64 cabinet_id = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp date_from = 2;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp date_to = 3;
}
```

Command which I use to get *.dsc:

```
protoc --include_imports --proto_path=src/main/proto/ --descriptor_set_out=descriptors/test.dsc  src/main/proto/test.proto
```

My code to load *.dsc files:

```
try (final InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(path)) {
            final FileDescriptorSet fds = FileDescriptorSet.parseFrom(stream);

            final TypeRegistry.Builder builder = TypeRegistry.newBuilder();
            for (final FileDescriptorProto fdp : fds.getFileList()) {
                final FileDescriptor fd = FileDescriptor.buildFrom(fdp, new FileDescriptor[]{});
                builder.add(fd.getMessageTypes());
                globalBuilder.add(fd.getMessageTypes());
            }
            return new Queue(base, builder.build());
        }
```

Comment: my app is in java

Answer (score 1):

`FileDescriptor.buildFrom(fdp, new FileDescriptor[]{})` is the key point.
You should build the dependency proto(import) recursively, and take the result to replace the second parameter.
Give you my code for reference

```
private FileDescriptor buildFileDescriptor(FileDescriptorProto currentFileProto,
                                           Map<String, FileDescriptorProto> fileProtoCache) {
    List<FileDescriptor> dependencyFileDescriptorList = new ArrayList<>();
    currentFileProto.getDependencyList().forEach(dependencyStr -> {
        FileDescriptorProto dependencyFileProto = fileProtoCache.get(dependencyStr);
        FileDescriptor dependencyFileDescriptor = buildFileDescriptor(dependencyFileProto, fileProtoCache);
        dependencyFileDescriptorList.add(dependencyFileDescriptor);
    });
    try {
        return FileDescriptor.buildFrom(currentFileProto, dependencyFileDescriptorList.toArray(new FileDescriptor[0]));
    } catch (DescriptorValidationException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("FileDescriptor build fail!", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but incase someone is looking to parse a .desc file with imports, this seemed to work for me:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(descPath);
DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet set = DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet.parseFrom(fin);

List<FileDescriptor> dependencyFileDescriptorList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<set.getFileCount()-1;i++) {
    dependencyFileDescriptorList.add(Descriptors.FileDescriptor.buildFrom(set.getFile(i), depndencyFileDescriptorList.toArray(new FileDescriptor[i]));
}
FileDescriptor desc = Descriptors.FileDescriptor.buildFrom(set.getFile(set.getFileCount()-1), dependencyFileDescriptorList.toArray(new FileDescriptor[0]));
```